# VBA Outlook Body Data modification with Default Signature

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, signature

I am trying to write some code which needs to have specific data while still retaining the Default signature as it is.

For example if i use the function .Body will replace then entire contents of the e-mail with the Body text.

```
Sub ListView41_DblClick()

Dim strName     As String
Dim strEmail    As String
Dim strEmail1   As String
Dim OutApp      As Object
Dim OutMail     As Object
Dim Singlepart  As String
Dim SigString   As String
Dim Signature   As String
Dim strbody As String
Dim SigFilename

strName = ListView41.SelectedItem.Text
strEmail = ListView41.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text
strEmail1 = ListView41.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(2).Text

check = MsgBox("Send e-mail, To : " & strName & " - " & strEmail & "?" & vbNewLine & _
"CC : " & strEmail1, vbYesNo)

'UserForm1.Show

If check <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Singlepart = MsgBox("For Single Part or Multiple Parts ? " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Single Part = Yes" & vbNewLine & _
"Multiple Parts = No", vbYesNo)

If Singlepart = vbYes Then

' For Single Part Numbers
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<H3><B>Dear Customer Ron de Bruin</B></H3>" & _
              "Please visit this website to download the new version.<br>" & _
              "Let me know if you have problems.<br>" & _
              "<A HREF=""http://www.rondebruin.nl/tips.htm"">Ron's Excel Page</A>" & _
              "<br><br><B>Thank you</B>"

'Signature of User
SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Rohith UTAS.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next


Userform1.Show


'With Outlook
         With OutMail
            .Display
            .To = strEmail
            .CC = strEmail1
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = strName & "_Request for Product Information"
            .HTMLBody = strbody & vbNewLine & Signature
            .Display 'or .Display if you want the user to view e-mail and send it manually
        End With

Else

' For Multiple Part Numbers
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Signature of User
SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Rohith UTAS.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

'With Outlook
        With OutMail
            .To = strEmail
            .CC = strEmail1
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = strName & "_Request for Product Information"
            .HTMLBody = "<br>" & _
                        "Hi," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                        "Can you please provide me the Lifecycle and Years of Availability for the below listed parts?" & "<br />" & "<br />" & _
                        "The list of parts are : " & "<br />" & "<br />" & "<br />" & "<br />" & "<br />" & "<br />" & Signature
            .Display 'or .Display if you want the user to view e-mail and send it manually
        End With

End If
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What exactly is your question?

Comment: This won't fix the problem, just simplify your code a bit: Pull the `'Signature of user` section of code out of both sides of the `If...Else...End If` and put it before the `If` - you're doing the exact same thing both times, no need to maintain the code twice.

Comment: Making the assumption though that you're not getting the signature added back into the body of the email, have you confirmed that your code is, in fact, correctly getting the signature text, or is it hitting the `Signature = ""` line?

Answer (score 0):

before writing to .body, check what's already in it to see if it pre-filled with the signature. If so, change your code to:

```
.body = newtext & .body
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include/add the signature template each time you create a new item. The default signature is added automatically, you just need to add the content at the beginning of the mail item as *rgo* suggested:

```
mailItem.HTMLBody = ModifyTheExistingBody(mailItem.HTMLBody);
```

Where the *ModifyTheExistingBody* function inserts a valid HTML tags into the HTML markup.

The Outlook object model provides three different ways for working with item bodies:

1. Body - a plain text.
2. HTMLBody - an HTML markup.
3. The Word Editor. Outlook uses Word as an email editor, so you can use it to format the email message. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: This should never be done:

mailItem.HTMLBody = htmlMarkupToAdd & mailItem.HTMLBody;

You cannot concatenate 2 HTML strings and expect a valid HTML result. If you need to insert something in the beginning of the HTML body, look for the “<body” substring, find the next instance of “>” (to take into account attributes on the body element), then insert your HTML string (without the html and body elements).

Comment: You are correct. The text (a valid HTML tags) should be inserted in the existing HTML markup.